# If $G = \langle a \rangle$ is a finite cyclic group of order $n$ then the order of every element of $G$ is a divisor of $n$ - correct proof?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

The following is from "Guide to Abstract Algebra, 1st Ed, Whitehead"

> Prove that if $G = \langle a \rangle$ is a finite cyclic group of order $n$ then the order of every element of $G$ is a divisor of $n$.

**Question**: Is the following correct?

I am self-teaching so do miss some key arguments required in apparently simple proofs.

---

**My solution:**

The finite cyclic group has order $n$, which means $a^n = e$, the identity element, where $a \in G$.

We construct $a^{jk} = e$, where $jk=n$, for integers $j,k$.

That is, $(a^j)^k = e.$

So the order of $a^j$ is $k$, and $k$ is a divisor of $n$, our objective.

What is left to show is that $a^j$ generates all elements of $G$. We can say it does because $1 \leq j \leq n$ generates all the elements within the first cycle of $G$.

Comment: Use `\langle,\rangle` to get the proper braces: $\langle a\rangle$

Comment: Your argument is hard to follow and incomplete.  At first you require $j$ to be a factor of $n$ (since you explicitly write $jk=n$) but later you switch to allowing any $j$ in the range $1≤j≤n$ but of course most of those will not be divisors of $n$.

Comment: It's hard to provide hints since we do not know what theorems are available to you.  If you know Bezout's Theorem then argue that " $g\in G$ satisfies $g^n=e$.  If the order of $g$ is $i$ then we also have $g^{\gcd(i,n)}=e$  which implies that $i\,|\,n$".

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem for finite group?Then you can prove a more stronger result. $$\\$$ Let $G$ be finite group and $a\in G$ then $a^{o(G) }=1$ i.e $o(a) \Big | o(G) $

Answer (score 1):

You might need to be clearer about where you start and what follows. You want to startt with an arbitrary element $b\in\langle a\rangle$, which can be represented by $b=a^j$ for some $1\le j\le n$, that at least is correct. But why would $j$ necessarily be a divisor of $n$? In general this is not true. But the statement "find $k$, such that $jk=n$" presumes, that $j$ must be a divisor of $n$. So no, I don't see how this is a full solution. If $j$ does divide $n$, then yes, you found a $k$, that satisfies the condition. But is it the least $k$? That is also required to be shown. I'd say you're not done here.

Instead, let's begin with an arbitrary element $b\in\langle a\rangle$. Then $b$ can be written as a power of $a$ as follows: $b=a^j$ for some fixed $j\le n$. Let's call $k$ the order $b$, i.e. $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $b^k=e$. We want to know how $k$ relates to $n$. Here we will apply the most useful concept for this proof: Euclidean Division, i.e. division with a remainder. We can always divide $n$ by $k$ with a remainder $r$ that satisfies $0\le r<k$. We know that there is some integer $p$ such that
$$n=pk+r.$$
On the other hand we can also divide $jk$ by $n$ with a remainder to find some integer $q$ and some $0\le R<n$ such that
$$jk=qn+R.$$
From here we want to use the fact that $n$ is the smallest integer the makes $a^n=e$ true (in particular $R$ can only satisfy $a^R=e$ if $R=0$, since it is smaller than $n$), and also the fact that $k$ is the smallest integer such that $b^k=e$ (and again $b^r=e$ only if $r=0$). Can you see a way to argue that uses both facts and shows that $k$ divides $n$? What would need to be true for $k$ to divide $n$?

Let me know if you needs more clarifications.

Comment: hi @Sellerie - thank you for this guidance, I will spend some time thinking about it. I would also appreciate advice on proving it in a different way that doesn't depend on more advanced theorems eg Lagrange's or Bezout's.

Comment: The proof I have in mind relies on the fact, that the order is always the least $k$ that satisfies $b^k=e$, i.e. the smallest non negative $k$. If you just call $k$ the order of $a^j$, then no smaller positive number will satisfy $(a^j)^r=e$. The same holds for $a^n=e$, there is also no smaller positive $r$ that allows for $a^r=e$. I will write out some of it in my answer as an edit.

Comment: Of course the first "non negative $k$" is supposed to say "positive integer $k$". It is not allowed to be $0$.

Comment: hi @Sellerie, thanks for taking the time to edit your answer. I've spent an hour with pen and paper and I can't get past the following statement "We can always divide $n$ by $k$". How do we know $n$ is always larger than $k$?. Intuitively it makes sense, but I can't see an objective reason.

Comment: if I move past the previous comment, then I can see that $a^n = e = a^{pk+r}=a^{pk} a^r$, which implies $r=0$ since $r < n$ and $n$ is the smallest positive integer that makes $a^n=e$. This looks sufficient to say $pk=n \implies k|n$. Again, my apologies if I'm oversimplifying again.

Comment: You can assume that $k$ is at most $n$, because we know that $b^n=(a^j)^n=a^{jn}=(a^n)^j=e^j=e$, so $n$ is already one such exponent, that makes $b^k=e$ true. So the smallest $k$ must be at most as big as $n$. Also, when it comes to your solution, which is already a good try, you need to ask yourself, why $a^pk=e$ should be true. That is what is needed there. In general this need not be true. Instead, you want to consider $e=(a^j)^n=\dots ?$. Do you see how that might help you more? What do you know about $a^j$ and $k$? With this approach you only need to argue the other equality.

Comment: hi @Sellerie - thanks for your helpful comments. I am really struggling so I plan to (1) re-read the chapter which introduces the topic, and (2) read other proofs such as this one https://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/cyclic-groups/cyclic-groups.pdf .. thank you for your patience with a self-teacher !

Comment: The Lemma on page 4 already does a lot of the work you are trying to figure out. Maybe make sure you understand very well what they're trying to do there and then check whether you can use that Lemma to show what you would like to show. Nonetheless good on you for self teaching! Good luck going forward. Enjoy abstract algebra!